# Doesn't work VideoCapture in openCV second time

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

When I run the script below for the first time, it runs correctly, but when I run it a second time, it fails. The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do mean by doesn't work? is there any error?

Comment: Write: select timeout

Comment: It times out? the error is 'Write: select timeout'?

Comment: the error is "select timeout"